# how to render a default component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a few routes defined

```
/ (homepage)
/:profile (something like /john and /mary to get user profile)
/backend/profile
/backend/files
```

this is my main file.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route
            path="/"}
            exact
            strict
            component={Homepage}
        />
        <Route
            path="/:profile"}
            exact
            strict
            component={Profile}
        />
        <Backend>
            <Route path="/backend/profile" exact strict component={BackendProfile} />
            <Route path="/backend/files" exact strict component={BackendFiles} />
        </Backend>
        <Route component={Homepage} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Everything works fine except when I enter a URL that's not defined.
I was expecting to render Homepage *component* but instead is rendering *Admin* component

note: I´m not adding here the components because I suspect the issue is how I configured the router

Comment: Did you try `path="*"` with your Homepage component? And please provide an example that can reproduce this issue

Comment: path="*" didn´t help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `Switch` returns and renders the first matching `Route` or `Redirect`. The caveat to this is that the component `Backend` isn't either of this and will always be rendered, so the "catch-all" homepage route is never reached.

## Solution

Render the backend into a route for it. I suggest also rendering a redirect to your homepage route as a fallback as well, so only one route is handling the homepage rendering.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/"}
      exact
      strict
      component={Homepage}
    />
    <Route
      path="/:profile"}
      exact
      strict
      component={Profile}
    />
    <Route
      path="/backend"
      render={() => (
        <Backend>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/backend/profile" exact strict component={BackendProfile} />
            <Route path="/backend/files" exact strict component={BackendFiles} />
          </Switch>
        </Backend>
      )}
    />
    <Redirect to="/" />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```